# Rounding value to .5

Tags: c#, .net

There are the obvious quirks of `Math.Round` but is there a way to make `Math.Round` fulfill this type of manipulation for a rating system.

If greater than `.0` and less than or equal to `.5`, display half a star

If greater than `.5` and less than or equal to `.0` display whole star

So obviously a half star would be `.5` and a whole start would be the next whole value.

I don't know of a rounding method to go to half whole numbers.

Should I just write if statements to control my rounding?

**Edit/Solution

From the below answer I came up with.

```
double roundedRating = (Math.Ceiling(2 * currentRating)) / 2;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd recommend multiplying by two, performing `Math.Ceiling`, and dividing by two to get to the nearest half.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misreading the question, but this doesnt seem like it would work for all values.  `0.7` would be rounded down to `0.5`, but I think he wants it rounded up to `1.0`

Comment: it won't work for 0.1 and 0.2. (2x0.1=0.2) round that and divide by 2

Comment: It's a good idea, but like stated above it's not quite spot on.

Comment: Fixed it guys! Math.ceiling is better

Comment: If it only needs to be in the range `[0, 1]` then it works. If it needs to go higher than that, it doesn't.  Starts to round up to the next whole number on `1.5` -> `2`. The `N.5` numbers are off after you pass `1`.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling(2.5*2)/2 => 2.5` works. Ceiling of a whole number is itself

Comment: Posted an edit above with what i am using that seems to be working.  Anyone see a use case that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to make sure that you end up performing your checks against integers, rather than floating point numbers.

Start by multiplying the number by 2.  Continue doing this until it's an integer value (no value in the decimal part).

Now, continuously divide by 2 until you end up with a number that's less than or equal to the original number.  If the result decimal part is greater than .0 and less than or equal to .5, display half a star.  If it's greater than .5 and less than or equal to +.0, display a whole star.

Actually, go with matt's answer.  ; )

Answer (score 1):

Can this work?

Multiply the number by 10 e.g. `0.1x10, 0.2x10` to get n

```
Math.Ceil(n / 5) / 2 
where n = 1, 2, 3 instead of - .1, .2, .3
```

examples:

```
1,2,3,4,5 = 1/2 = 0.5
6,7,8,9,10 = 2/2 = 1
11,12,13,14,15 = 3/2 = 1.5
```

Comment: This does work - because `n * 10 / 5` reduces to `n * 2` which is exactly Matt's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is no issue, the following approach could be used:

```
Number *= 10;
Number % 10 = remainder;
if(remainder <=5 && remainder != 0)
  //Half star
else
  //Whole star
```

However, that code is kinda ugly, but I think it gives you the general idea.

Comment: This is kind of the approach I was thinking.  Anyone have a bit more friendly way of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
double roundedRating = (int)(currentRating * 2D + 0.999999999999999) / 2D
```